# DDD, доменные службы и события

Tags: события, service, ddd

**Ситуация:**

Для работы с доменными событиями Джимми Богартом был предложен [способ](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/05/13/a-better-domain-events-pattern/) сохранения событий в агрегатах.

Это, с моей точки зрения, очень удобный подход. Однако как быть в случае возникновения доменного события в доменной службе?

Доменная служба не должна иметь состояния (stateless). В таком случае, по идее, в конструктор такой службы необходимо передавать диспетчер событий IDispatcher.

**Вопрос:**

Чтобы избежать внедрения в доменную службу диспетчера событий насколько корректны предложенные альтернативные подходы:

1. Сохранение в доменной службе событий последней операции. Однако это нарушит принцип stateless для доменной службы.
2. Возврат перечня событий из метода службы по результатам операции (в return метода или другим способом в зависимости от возможностей языка программирования).

Comment: Проще на мой взгляд завести реестр для таких независимых событий и его уже внедрять в конструктор службы. Он заберет на себя все проблемы состояния и с помощью контроля время жизни реестра можно на каждую транзакцию свои инстанс создавать, а по окончанию обработать и уничтожить.